# Is there a way to deploy images to Firebase hosting, but only where changes exist?

Tags: angular, firebase, angular-cli, firebase-storage, firebase-hosting

I deploy my Angular2 site to Firebase hosting, but the 'dist' folder always sends the entire image collection in the 'assets' folder, even if they haven't changed. This takes up more bandwidth than necessary, as this folder is larger than all the other files combined.

How can I deploy ONLY the changed images?
The strategy would be:

**A)** Configure the Firebase CLI "*deploy*" command to process only changed images

AND/OR

**B)** Configure the Angular production build to only package the changed images (though this would still require Firebase to update the 'assets' folder instead of overriding all the other, unchanged images on deployment)

Firebase Storage is not a good alternative as I've seen...making the API calls to access the images on page load only slows down the load time...unless there is a caching strategy involved in this? At the end of the day, the solution needs to involve the CDN and the CLI working together to minimize bandwidth and load/deployment time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry, there are currently no partial deploys for Firebase Hosting static content.

An alternative might be to host your images in one project and everything else in another project.  If your images don't change very often, then you won't have to deploy to the project with your images if nothing changes.

You could also use Storage to store your images, then serve them via [Cloud Functions integration with Firebase Hosting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions), which can do the lookup dynamically and proxy the image to the client.  Hosting can then be configured to cache the images at the CDN, [as described in the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions#managing_cache_behavior).

You might also see some gains if you instead record the Storage download URL for the images in Realtime Database as opposed to asking Storage to generate one, and having the client look there instead.

Comment: Nice @DougStevenson, thank you much! Wish I could give you extra points for the fast response :)

Comment: I found [this link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/#partial_deploys) particularly interesting from your references. If I understand correctly, using the methodologies you described, I can further control my deployments with the "--only" command and never have to leave the CLI for content updates!

Comment: Right, you can `firebase deploy --only hosting` to send only your hosting content and nothing else (though the entire set of files will always be sent).  You can see that functions have better partial deploy support for updating single functions at a time.  With Cloud Storage, you can use the gcloud command line to upload individual files.

Comment: Instead of two projects it is also possible to have multiple "sites" in one project. I think I will go this way. https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/multisites